# Driver for ATI Radeon x1350

Tags: 12.10, ati

I've a laptop with ATI Radeon X1350. I have problem with display in Ubuntu 12.10 , the system is slow.
I think that the problem is in the GPU. Can I find an update to it ?

Comment: What do you mean "slow" and why do you think i'ts because of the GPU?. AMD had dropped support for that card a long time ago newer drivers doesn't support it. What are your other specs?, try another Desktop Environment.

Comment: By saying "slow": do you mean it is generally slow or just when invoking dash/HUD?

Comment: What is your problem with the display? Is it just the slowness, or is there something else?

Comment: First, I had a problem with installation until I deactivated nomodeset. then after installation I could not enter Ubuntu before I add 'nomodeset' to the grub editor.
for 'slow', I see that animations are slow like fades.

Comment: is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (on a T60 with ATI X1300):

1. install compizconfig-settings-manager
2. start it by typing `ccsm` in a terminal window or in the dash
3. In Category *Desktop* click on *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*
4. Select the tab *Experimental*
5. scroll down until you see *Dash Blur*
6. select *No Blur*
7. I also selected a different type for *Hide Animation*

[image]